# How to bind EDM to WPF ListBox?

Tags: wpf, ado.net, binding, edmx

I'm trying to figure out WPF binding to SQLite.

I have an ADO.NET Entity Data Model generated to represent my SQLite database. The database only holds one table "People" with two columns "person_id" and "person_name". Now, I generated EDM classes for that table within my WPF Application.

I'm trying to bind to a list box. I can delete items from source and see it updating the list box. But I can't add items to the source using a text box and see it update the list box.

I declared data entities in Window1 class like this:

```
private static MyNewSqliteDbEntities2 _myEntities = new MyNewSqliteDbEntities2();
```

I have a list box that is bound to the ObjectQuery in the  Window_Loaded event handler like this:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    peopleListBox.ItemsSource = _myEntities.People;
}
```

I have another text box which I use to add people by clicking on button. And I can delete Items by selecting an item in the list box and clicking delete button. Changes are committed to the database when a commit button is clicked. Please consider the code below:

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (addPersonTextBox.Text != "")
    {
        People newPerson = new People();
        newPerson.person_name = addPersonTextBox.Text;
        //_myEntities.AddToPeople(newPerson);
        _myEntities.AddObject("People", newPerson);

        addPersonTextBox.Text = "";
    }
}

private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _myEntities.DeleteObject(peopleListBox.SelectedItem);
}

private void commitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _myEntities.SaveChanges();
}
```

I tried refreshing the list box control using another button called "Refresh" in the following manner but with no luck (although, when I step through the code I see the source is updated):

```
private void refreshButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    peopleListBox.ItemsSource = null;
    peopleListBox.ItemsSource = _myEntities.People;
}
```

Here is the XAML code if you are wondering:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingToSqLite.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="400" Width="400" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="personNameTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=person_name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="190*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="94*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="94*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="182*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="38*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="38*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="32*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Margin="5" Name="peopleListBox" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource personNameTemplate}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,10" Name="addPersonTextBox" />
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Name="addButton" Click="addButton_Click">Add</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" Name="commitButton" Click="commitButton_Click">Commit</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" Name="deleteButton" Click="deleteButton_Click">Delete</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Margin="5" Name="refreshButton" Click="refreshButton_Click">Refresh</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this completely wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `People` property needs to be an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) for this to work.

Comment: Yes, but ADO.net EDM does not generate ObservableCollection<People>.

Comment: @mbadawi23, in this case you might need to use a view model and map between your EDM model and the view model (MVVM pattern).